# Copy HDFS files from multiple source folders to ADLS Gen2 Storage

Tags: hadoop, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I've a requirement like: I'll have to copy files (zip format) from HDFS (Hadoop File Systems) to ADLS Gen2 Blob storage through ADF pipelines. The file formats in HDFS systems like:

```
HDFS Source:
    hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition1/customer/full/2023-04-01/customer.zip
    hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition1/customer/full/2023-04-02/customer.zip
    hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition1/customer/full/2023-04-03/customer.zip
    hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition2/parts/full/2023-04-01/parts.zip
    hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition2/parts/full/2023-04-02/parts.zip
    hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition2/parts/full/2023-04-03/parts.zip
    hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition3/modules/full/2023-04-01/modules.zip
    hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition3/modules/full/2023-04-02/modules.zip
    hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition3/modules/full/2023-04-03/modules.zip
    hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition4/events/full/2023-04-01/events.zip
    hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition4/events/full/2023-04-02/events.zip
    hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition4/events/full/2023-04-03/events.zip

ADLS Target should be:
    adls/consolidated/synova/raw/partition1/customer/2023-04-01/customer.zip
                                                /2023-04-02/customer.zip
                                                /2023-04-03/customer.zip
    adls/consolidated/synova/raw/partition2/parts/2023-04-01/parts.zip
                                             /2023-04-02/parts.zip
                                             /2023-04-03/parts.zip
    adls/consolidated/synova/raw/partition3/modules/2023-04-01/modules.zip
                                               /2023-04-02/modules.zip
                                               /2023-04-03/modules.zip
    adls/consolidated/synova/raw/partition4/events/2023-04-01/events.zip
                                              /2023-04-02/events.zip
                                              /2023-04-03/events.zip
```

I need to create a Generic ADF pipelines to copy these files.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be done using **Get meta data activity**(to list files) and copy activity. But it requires lot of child pipelines for the subfolders because Get Meta data cannot give the path for nested subfolders.

For getting the list of paths, you can try by code with databricks(Notebook activity) or functions and get that list in ADF.

If you want to do it only in ADF, then go through this [blog](https://richardswinbank.net/adf/get_metadata_recursively_in_azure_data_factory) by @**Richard Swinbank** for getting the list of files recursively.

After getting the list, Give it to ForEach activity and inside ForEach, Give the `@item()` to copy activity source file path and for sink file path, replace the `'/full'` in `@item()` with empty string.

Here, this is the files list I have taken for sample and given it to a ForEach:

```
["synova/raw/partition1/customer/full/2023-04-01/customer.zip",
"synova/raw/partition1/customer/full/2023-04-02/customer.zip",
"synova/raw/partition1/customer/full/2023-04-03/customer.zip",
"synova/raw/partition2/parts/full/2023-04-01/parts.zip",
"synova/raw/partition2/parts/full/2023-04-02/parts.zip",
"synova/raw/partition2/parts/full/2023-04-03/parts.zip",
"synova/raw/partition3/modules/full/2023-04-01/modules.zip",
"synova/raw/partition3/modules/full/2023-04-02/modules.zip",
"synova/raw/partition3/modules/full/2023-04-03/modules.zip",
"synova/raw/partition4/events/full/2023-04-01/events.zip",
"synova/raw/partition4/events/full/2023-04-02/events.zip",
"synova/raw/partition4/events/full/2023-04-03/events.zip"]
```

**My source dataset:**

[image]

**sink dataset:**

[image]

Inside ForEach, give the `@item()` to source file path and store the replaced value in a variable.

```
@replace(item(),'/full','')
```

[image]

Give this variable for the sink file path.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rakesh but how can I loop through the child folders in HDFS source system in ADF, GetMedata activity does not support HDFS Linked services. My scenario is I've a source like this: hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition1/customer/full/2023-04-01/01-00/customer.zip hdfs/data/users/synova/raw/partition1/customer/full/2023-04-01/02-00/customer.zip & I'd like to copy those files into ADLS path: synova/raw/partition1/customer/full/2023-04-01/01-00/customer.zip So in ADF pipeline, it should check in ADLS if the "02-00" folder is unavailable then it should copy folder "02-00" else just ignore